# Using The + Alias In G-Mail

Tags: email, gmail

I recently started using the `+` symbol method in GMail to set up multiple accounts relating to my personal email address (`social , personal , work , etc`), and now I want to use the same method for my business.

But, I'm wondering how to format my emails properly as I have some sub-divisions under my parent business. Is it possible to use multiple `+` symbols, or is it best to use a `.` or a `-`?

I'll give an example:

```
business@gmail.com // Main Business Email

business+subdivision@gmail.com // Sub Division Email

business+subdivision+contact@gmail.com
business+subdivision-contact@gmail.com
business+subdivision.contact@gmail.com
```

Any recommendations as to which can, or should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get one '+' per email address, but you're free to use '-' or '.' (or both) after the plus. In your case, all the these would be valid:

```
business+subdivision-contact@gmail.com
business+subdivision.contact@gmail.com
business+another-subdivision.contact-name@gmail.com
```

...and so on. Basically the plus has to come immediately after the primary address and anything that follows (except another plus) is ignored.

Comment: Thank you. I like the way you've used multiple dashes and the dot in the third line of your example. Very useful for what I want to achieve.